# Regex Extract String

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string:

```
string s = "GameObject.Find(\"MyObj\").GetComponent(\"MyComponent\")";
```

I want to extract "GameObject.Find(\"MyObj\")" where MyObj can include any number or type of characters except newline.

This is my code:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(s, "GameObject.Find(\".+\")");
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure where to go from here. How can we make this expression work as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Match match = Regex.Match(s, "GameObject.Find(\".+?\")");
```

You should do non-greedy search, but beware that it will only match from parantheses+quotation mark to first quotation mark+parantheses.

So for,

```
string s = "GameObject.Find(\"seckin(\\\"hand\\\").thumb()\").GetComponent(\"MyComponent\")"
```

it will match `"GameObject.Find(\"seckin(\\\"hand\\\")"`

But there is no way to match enclosing parenthesis using RegExp, so it is the best sub-optimal solution.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should try :

```
Match match = Regex.Match(s, "GameObject.Find(\".+?\")");
```

Comment: I'm faster than you, my friend

Comment: Agree with you...My typing is very slow!!